# How to use contents of array as variables without using eval()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a list of variables or variable names stored in an array. I want to use them in a loop, but I don't want to have to use `eval()`. How do I do this? If I store the values in an array with quotes, I have to use `eval()` on the right side of any equation to render the value. If I store just the variable name, I thought I'd be storing the actual variable, but it's not working right.

```
$(data.xml).find('Question').each(function(){
  var answer_1 = $(this).find("Answers_1").text();
  var answer_2 = $(this).find("Answers_2").text();
  var answer_3 = $(this).find("Answers_3").text();
  var answer_4 = $(this).find("Answers_4").text();
  var theID = $(this).find("ID").text();
  var theBody = $(this).find("Body").text();

  var answerArray = new Array();

  answerArray = [answer_1,answer_2,answer_3,answer_4,theID,theBody]

  for(x=0;x<=5;x++) {
    testme = answerArray[x];

    alert("looking for = " + answerArray[x] + ", which is " + testme)
  }
});
```

Comment: I assume you mean **#** Answers _N_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the values themselves in an array:

```
var answers = [
    $(this).find("Answers_1").text(),
    $(this).find("Answers_2").text(),
    $(this).find("Answers_3").text(),
    $(this).find("Answers_4").text()
];

for(x=0;x<=5;x++) {
    alert("looking for = " + x + ", which is " + answers[x])
}
```

**EDIT**: Or even

```
var answers = $(this)
    .find("Answers_1, Answers_2, Answers_3, Answers_4")
    .map(function() { return $(this).text(); })
    .get();
```

If your answers share a common class, you can change the selector to `$(this).find('.AnswerClass')`.

If you need variable names, you can use an associate array:

```
var thing = { 
    a: "Hello",
    b: "World"
};

var name = 'a';
alert(thing[name]);
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have real associative arrays though; you would just be using an object as one. This can fail if you have such keys as "__proto" (in Firefox) and other special names.

Comment: However, those two code-snippets are not equivalent (just as a sidenote)

Comment: @idealmachine, a JavaScript object is an associative array, it has some abilities beyond a basic associative array, but that doesn't make it less a such. I don't see any odd behavior in Firefox resulting from using `"__proto"` as a key, would you care to elaborate?

Comment: @eBusiness: I meant `__proto__`; sorry about the typo. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto Try `var a = {}; a['__proto__'] = "foo"; alert(a);`.

Comment: Properties can usually be overloaded, it seems strange that this one can't.

Answer (score 1):

This would make it easier to get the array populated.

```
var answers = new Array();
$("Answers_1, Answers_2, Answers_3, Answers_4", this).text(function(index, currentText) {
  answers[index] = currentText;
});
```

Comment: @SLaks ...wouldn't this be easier to get the array populated.

Comment: You can be even cleverer.  See my answer.

Comment: @SLaks...yeah that one came to me just after I wrote this.

Comment: I believe you don't have to supply a jQuery object as the context, just supplying `this` works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, if you can put the variables in an array or an object, you will be able to access them more cleanly.

You can, however, access the variables through the `window` object:

```
var one = 1;
var two = 2;
var three = 3;

var varName = "one";

alert(window[varName]); // -> equivalent to: alert(one);
```

Of course, you can assign the `varName` variable any way like, including while looping through an array.